# LibGit2Sharp Create a Pull Request by adding one or more reviewers option?

Tags: git, request, pull, libgit2sharp

I am using .NET 5.0 Using libgit2sharp 0.26.0, I've written code to create a new branch, change some files, push branch to bitbucket. Now I need to create a pull-request and add a reviewer to it. However, my Google searches don't turn up any relevant info. Does libgit2sharp support creating PRs by adding reviewer?
I am using Commands.Pull(repo, signature, pullOptions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Libgit2sharp is a library to manage a local git repository.
A pull request is more a notion of Git hosting websites (Github, Bitbucket,...) .

**So you won't be able to create a PR with libgit2sharp.**

Side note: the `Pull` method that you try to use is the equivalent of `git pull` to be able to fetch commits from a remote repository and integrate them with a merge.

If you want to create a PR from your program, you will have to use the bitbucket APIs or use a library that wraps them like https://github.com/lvermeulen/Bitbucket.Cloud.Net (not tested).

In all cases, you will need to manage the authentication (surely using a token generated from bitbucket website)

Comment: Hi Philippe, Thanks for reply, but this is surprising, libgit2sharp provide feature for merging, so without creating a remote pull request, how it can be merged with this package?

Comment: @Ajay As said in my answer, you are handling your local repository so this is for merging 2 local branches and not merging a pull request. In your work flow, the merge will be done by Bitbucket. I don't know why it is surprising as the `git merge` command exists and allows you to do that...